# php: only execute the page if get the parameter

Tags: php

My **mainpage.php** is opened after user login in the **login.html**.

The step of login: l**ogin.html -> checkLogin.php -> mainpage.php**

Now, i use  `$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id` in **checkLogin.php** and `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']` in the **mainpage.php**. However, the **mainpage.php** must only be executed when get the `user_id`. If not, it will display a "pleases login again !" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that it exists:

```
// mainpage.php
if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    die('pleases login again !');
}
```